# Perl Regex - Exact Match

Tags: regex

I am trying to put together a regex that searches logs for commands run against a file (".pan").

For example:

- cat .pan
- less .pan
- cp .pan somedir

The file will only be named ".pan"

I am interested in any thing before or after the file name, but the regex should only be interested in the file named ".pan".

Originally I was using the regex:

```
.\.pan
```

But I started seeing results such as:

```
command .pans 
command .panyx extra characters
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: Try `/\B\.pan\b/`,

Comment: I'd use whitespace boundary's `(?<!\S)\.pan(?!\S)` and stay out of trouble.

Comment: If my answer did not solve your issue please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a non-word boundary (`\B`) before `.` and a word boundary (`\b`) after `pan`:

```
\B\.pan\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uwyGjL/1)

The `\B\.` will match any dot that is not preceded with a word char and `n\b` will match any `n` that is not followed with a word char.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  I am new to regex and will read up on \B & \b

Comment: Note that `(?<!\S)\.pan(?!\S)` will require  start/end of string or space on both sides. I'd still recommend (non)word boundaries.